# Task tags in Vim

Tags: vim

Two questions regarding task tags:

What other task tags like TODO, is available in Vim? 
Is there any way to make custom task tags like in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: `TODO`, `XXX`, and `FIXME` are all I know.  Someone follow up please?

Comment: I'm guessing these all the standard ones that comes with vanilla vim, unless we edit the c.vim file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like all syntax highlighting, `TODO`, `FIXME`, `XXX`, *et cetera* depend on which type of file you are editing. These keywords are defined in the [syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) files for your chosen language.

The examples I quoted are from [`c.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/c.vim)

Vim is open source: feel free to [browse the repository](https://github.com/vim/vim/)!

Comment: Thanks, Vim has a quite steep learning curve, still digesting it

Answer (score 23):

For custom tags I use the following in my .vimrc, you should be able to adjust it to your needs.

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Highlight TODO, FIXME, NOTE, etc.
  if v:version > 701
    autocmd Syntax * call matchadd('Todo',  '\W\zs\(TODO\|FIXME\|CHANGED\|XXX\|BUG\|HACK\)')
    autocmd Syntax * call matchadd('Debug', '\W\zs\(NOTE\|INFO\|IDEA\)')
  endif
endif
```

This enables highlighting of these keywords in all files.  `\W\zs` ensures that there is a word break in front of the match, mainly to prevent DEBUG and others from being highlighted partially.

Comment: this stopped working after installing YouCompleteMe! Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Paschalis: No idea, never used that plugin. Maybe they clear/redefine some syntax rules and that gets rid of these rules. (Couldn't find anything obvious with the limited github search, and don't have time right now to search more.) If that's what happens, you might try to find the place that triggers the re-definition/clearing and hook the re-definition of your rules to the same thing. Or maybe ask them if they know why and if there's a better way to do this. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @nobody! Btw the plugin  definitely worths a try! ;)

Comment: Oh god! This didn't worked because I 've accidentally moved it before `syntax on` !

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have mentioned, there's also TBD.